# Javascript: Why am I getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to register an event handler that appends an element into the DOM when a button fires a click event,e.g.

```
var b = document.getElementById('evt');

var eventDemo = function(event) {

    console.log('I handled the event');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(event)); 

var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/';
document.body.appendChild(imgElement);

};

b.addEventListener('onclick', eventDemo, false);
```

but I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Why is this happening

Browser: chrome

Comment: Because element with `evt` id don't exists

Comment: It means that there's no element in the DOM (at the time that code runs) with id "evt".  It means that variable `b` contains `null`.

Comment: Also, use the 'click' event, not 'onclick'.

Comment: yes the HTML has the element `evt`. script is loaded from file `script.js`. tried `click` but read somewhere that chrome doesnt support `click`?

Comment: @user4668401 is `script.js` added in `head` tag

Comment: yes its added in head tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've said that `script` is loaded in `head` tag, by the time when the statement

```
var b = document.getElementById('evt');
```

is executed, there is no element in the `DOM` having id `evt`.

Use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event to add event listeners on element. This will run after the `DOM` is completely loaded.

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event - load - should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly popular mistake for people to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more appropriate, so be cautious.

Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var b = document.getElementById('evt');
    b.addEventListener('click', eventDemo, false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The error itself clearly explains! You don't have any html element with the id 'evt'. If you are sure you have an element with id 'evt', then use `$(document).ready` as given below, so that, your js gets executed when the html elements are loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var b = document.getElementById('evt');

var eventDemo = function(event) {

    console.log('I handled the event');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(event)); 

var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/';
document.body.appendChild(imgElement);

};

b.addEventListener('onclick', eventDemo, false);
});
```

Comment: the element exists in the HTML and if I check for it in the console. As Tushar and Barth Zalewski pointed out - it was because my script ran before the `body` or anything else was loaded

Comment: See my edit. Using $(document).ready() will make sure your javascript executes only when your html page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

At the point when this script runs, the element with id 'evt' is not defined. There are two possibilities:

1. You misspelled the id or forgot to add it, double-check it
2. You load this code before the page gets rendered. You say, you load this script from `script.js`, so it probably happens in `<head>`. But when the script is loaded, the `<body>` still isn't.

Either add this script at the bottom of the page, or, better, use the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //place all your code here
});
```

And, as somebody already mentioned, the event is called `click`, not `onclick`. The `onclick` is a DOM property, say, an equivalent in HTML to `addEventListener`.

Should you ever happen to use jQuery, the convenient wrapper is `$(document).ready(function() { /* place hode here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```
element = document.getElementById(id);
```

element is a reference to an Element object, or *null* if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.

In your case b is not found and returning null. Null is not an object so it cannot have `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same kind of error and I wasted my 2 days on the same.
Later found out that the same application was working fine on firefox.
So I tried updating my chrome version to 53.x.x
And now no such issue is occurring.
Maybe this will help you too :)